# Customize HtmlHelper.ValidationMessage output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, customization

Is it possible (and how) to customize the HTML output of the `HtmlHelper.ValidationMessage` extension method in Asp.net MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than passing in some html attributes, you will have to roll your own extension method if you need full customization (for example, to have it render as a `<div>` instead of `<span>`)

I would copy the ValidationMessage method from the mvc source code and customize it as needed.

Comment: Exactly what I just did. Had to copy original code (+2 privates) and built my own code.

Comment: yuck... I was afraid of this.

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 2 will provide the ability to customize the message. For ASP.NET MVC 1.0, Kurt's solution does the trick.

Comment: That's nice to hear. But it's will still probably just be able to customize HTML element... It would be best to customize even more complex HTML creation. For instance I have a DIV with a child DIV. Child DIV displays the message... Anyway. MVC2 probably won't be configurable to this level, will it?

Comment: You'll be able to have any custom HTML markup you want. If you choose this approach, we'll simply toggle the visibility of the message via a CSS class. So yes, you'll be able to do this.